# Get Scope value during test

Tags: javascript

I am writing a test and trying to evaluate that a certain field was used.

During debugging I am able to see the value as expected.

But how can I call it in my test. Cos the way I use it, it comes as undefined.

Please see screenshot showcasing that value I want which is ref.

I want to call it in code as follows to fetch that value, but it is undefined.

```
dynamicContent["[[Scopes]]"] // this is already defined. 
dynamicContent["[[Scopes]]"]["0"].tkn // I want this value.
```

How could I fetch that value. I mean it is there, there has to be something wrong

in the way I am calling it. Please advice. Thanks.

Just as an example, the following works and able to get the value.

```
dynamicContent['__proto__']
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot access `[[Scopes]]` at all because it is a hidden property of the object. However, because `tkn` is in a closure, you may be able to access it, as it is defined somewhere above in the parent scopes. If so, it can just be accessed by its name. The problem is, I dont know when and how it was defined so cannot pin point how to access it. You should read more about Scopes and Closures in JavaScript.